# pine-script, strategy.exit does not work on condition

Tags: pine-script

there are the conditions.

```
OL = (ind==1 and new_efi==1) #open long cond
XL = (new_efi==-1 or ind==-1) #close long cond 

OS= (ind==-1 and new_efi==-1) #open short cond
XS= (new_efi==1 or ind==1) #close short cond
```

They are plotted well on chart, but the strategy.exit function does not run on XL and XS conditions.

```
strategy.exit("XL","EL", when = XL, loss=4000)
strategy.exit("XL","ES", when = XS,  loss=4000)

strategy.entry("EL", true, size, when = OL)
strategy.entry("ES", false, size, when = OS)
```

any ideas?

Comment: btw, strategy.exit works at loss condition